# Can `map` be used in `useSelector`?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to use a `map` inside `useSelector`. Is there any restrictions or good coding practice that prohibits the use of it?

```
const { items } = useSelector((state: any) => ({
   items: state.appReducer.items.map((item: any) => {
      return { itemID: item.id, itemDescription: item.desc }
   })
}))
```

Comment: It's just another function.

Comment: Where is `useEffect` used here?  Why do you think you can't use `.map()`?  Have you tried?  Have you observed any kind of problem?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any problem and it works perfectly. But one of my teammate is suggesting that it shouldn't be used, and I couldn't find any restriction in the documentation. So I thought I'd post it in here to see what others think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, but your selector is buggy. `useSelector` will run your selector after *every* dispatched action, and force the component to re-render whenever the selector returns a new value reference:

- https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates

Your selector is *always* returning a new object, and so it will *always* cause this component to re-render, **even if the relevant data in the store didn't change**.

I'd recommend reading through these sections of the Redux docs to understand how to write selectors that will perform better:

- https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react#react-redux-patterns
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-7-standard-patterns#memoized-selectors
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-6-performance-normalization#improving-render-performance

Answer (score 1):

That's a useSelector and not a useEffect.

For using `map` inside hooks, it's just a looping executing a synchronous callback function. So, there is nothing to worry about here.